# Как в where() указать в качестве значения поле таблицы из которой идет выборка?

Tags: yii2, yii, запрос, activerecord

Есть sql запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM article a
INNER JOIN category_article ca
ON a.id=ca.article_id WHERE ca.category_id = 2
AND EXISTS(
   SELECT 1 FROM category_article WHERE article_id = a.id AND category_id = 9
)
```

Для Active Record переписал его таким образом:

```
$query = Article::find();
$query->innerJoinWith(['categories'], false)->andWhere(['category.id' => 2]);
$query->andWhere(['exists', (new \yii\db\Query())
  ->from('category_article')
  ->where(['article_id' => 'article.id']) // Указать поле нужно тут
  ->andWhere(['category_id' => 9])
]);
$query->all()
```

Проблема ActiveRecord в том, что в `->where(['article_id' => 'article.id'])` значение `article.id` воспринимается не как поле `id` таблицы `article`, а как текстовое значение. Как можно указать поле таблицы `article` в условии?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно так:

```
->where(['article_id' => yii\db\Expression('article.id')])
```

Answer (score 1):

По канонам Вам не нужно это условие, если прописаны связи в этих сущностях

**В Category_Article**

```
public function getArticles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Article::className(), ['id' => 'article_id']);
}
```

**В Article**

```
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(CategoryArticles::className(), ['article_id' => 'id']);
}
```

А вот и сам запрос

```
$query = Article::find();
$query->innerJoinWith(['category'], false)->andWhere(['category.id' => 2]);
$query->andWhere(['exists', (new \yii\db\ActiveQuery())
  ->from('category_article')
  ->with(['article']) // Указать поле нужно тут
  ->andWhere(['category_id' => 9])
]);
$query->all()
```

Comment: Здравый смысл мне подсказывает что вы правы, только не могу разобраться как изменить запрос используя указанные связи

Comment: @EvgeniiZaets дополнил ответ

Comment: Так это же построитель запросов. \yii\db\Query() не имеет метода with()

Comment: @EvgeniiZaets Вам принципиально именно его использовать? Замените его на \yii\db\ActiveQuery()